# Ecrion single List repetition in a table format

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, ecrion

Ecrion Design Studio Publisher
I have to show this list in a table format.

XML List is:

```
<Drugs footer="Table Footer" >
    <Drug description="Type B"><Block>1</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type A"><Block>2</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type B"><Block>3</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type V" ><Block>4</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type L"><Block>5</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type J"><Block>6</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type B"><Block>7</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type A"><Block>8</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type B"><Block>9</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type V" ><Block>10</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type L"><Block>11</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type J"><Block>12</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type W"><Block>13</Block></Drug>
    <Drug description="Type S"><Block>14</Block></Drug>
</Drugs>
```

Required output:

[image: Required Output]

Comment: Please check now, i have made some changes in my question.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: How to display the required Xml dynamic list into ecrion design.Problem is that list will display in a single repetititng coloumn or row. i have to divide this if drug list extend to 7 nodes, how to divide this list into two rows/columns.

Comment: So what have you tried? Do you want to produce HTML, XSL-FO, or something else?

Comment: yes i have to produce its XSL-FO

Comment: Which XSLT version are you using?  Grouping is much easier in XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 3.0 than in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: am using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/questions/24311352